# MySQL query with UUID's really slow

Tags: mysql

I have the following query example:

```
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*, tableA.uuid as tableAuuid 
FROM tableA, tableB 
WHERE tableA.userUUID = 
      '51ce8ea9533da73640d84324731d67014e077fc8536ssdsdsdsdwqz79603' 
  AND tableB.uuid = tableA.tableBUUID
ORDER BY Date ASC, depTime ASC 
LIMIT 194, 18
```

Recently I have added uuid's essantially as a 'secondary' key due to allow offline functionality and sync.

Currenty the UUID's are just stored as a random string in a varchar field

The above query is really slow like takes around 10 seconds. But the original query which is

```
tableB.id=tableA.tableBId
```

which are auto inc primary keys are really fast.

I am wondering how to make the queries with UUID's faster

Comment: Do you have an index on your UUID's field?

Comment: You should also early on decide how to use UUID in the database https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/

Comment: **`1).`** Use `JOIN` syntax, which has been around for three decades now.  **`2).`** You can still join on the primary key and filter by the 'secondary' key...  `tableA INNER JOIN tableB on tableB.id=tableA.tableBId WHERE tableA.userUUID = '51ce8ea9533da73640d84324731d67014e077fc8536ssdsdsdsdwqz79603'`

Comment: The performance problem with [_UUIDs_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) .  The problem with [_Pagination_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/Pagination) via `OFFSET`.  If you don't need all `*` columns, spell out only the ones you need; this _may_ help with performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search by UUID, you are filtering the data and the engine needs to find the rows you want only, not any rows of the table(s).

In this case the query can benefit from the index:

```
create index ix1 on tableA (userUUID, tableBUUID);
```

Comment: This is what I was missing across all my tables. Thank you

Comment: @Maverick1994 - If that does not help 'enough', please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`